# Ruby game frameworks that are still actively maintained?

Tags: ruby, game-engine

I'm finding it very difficult to survey the options for game programming in Ruby. Several wrappers and frameworks that are mentioned in other posts and articles are no longer maintained or in use.

**Gosu / Ruby** seems to still be active: there's been a steady amount of chatter on the official forums.

Any other **actively maintained game frameworks for ruby**?

EDIT: I discovered a healthy amount of game development going on with **MacRuby**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using a couple of such frameworks. And I switched to [Rubygame](http://rubygame.org/) from Gosu. Rubygame codebase is not being often updated in last six months, **but people still rock**.

As for me, Rubygame is more convenient. It is subjective, but I am writing a 3D strategic game with units which can be controlled by players' Ruby code; this task is much harder to implement using Gosu.

P.S. May be 'actively maintained' is not what you really want. What is the framework problem which you think can be resolved by active maintenance?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I want to avoid the situation: beginning to use a framework, hit a showstopper bug in it, and then find out ... the maintainer has been out of contact for a year, or there's no community around it currently using it, or the bug has been known for years and won't be fixed...

Comment: Yes, I understand your concerns. The answer is: if community is grown enough, a maintainer doesn't affect product a lot. So his absence either. Exactly that's why I emphasized "**but people still rock**".